# how to configure mongodb index for sorting by value within time range with certain type?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection like below

```
transfer_collection
    - type
    - value
    - from
    - to
    - timestamp
```

What I want to extract from the collection is the highest 100 values with certain type within certain time period.

For example,

```
db.getCollection('transfer_collection').find({$and:[{"type":"normal"}, {"timestamp":{$gte:ISODate("2018-01-10T00:00:00.000Z")}}, {"timestamp":{$lt:ISODate("2018-01-11T00:00:00.000Z")}}]}).sort({"value":-1}).limit(100)
```

## My question is, for query performance, how to make index?

1. {timestamp:1, type:1, value:-1}
2. {type:1, timestamp:1, value:-1}
3. {type:1, value:-1, timestamp:1}
4. any other else?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query, the compound index on `{ type: 1, timestamp: 1, value: -1 }` looks like an obvious choice. But, it is not so.

The keys in a compound index are used in a query's sort *only* if the query conditions before the sort have equality condition, *not* range conditions (using operators like `$gte`, `$lt`, etc.), as in this case where the key before sort is not an equality condition `("timestamp":{$gte:ISODate....`

This requires the organization of the index as: `{ type: 1,  value: -1, timestamp: 1 }`

This is a **concept** called as **Equality, Sort and Range**; the keys of the compound index are to be in that order - the `type` field with *equality* condition, the `value` field with the *sort* operation, and the *rage condition* for the `timestamp` field.

**Verify** this by running the `explain()` function with the query. Use "executionStats" *mode* and check the results. The query plan should have a `winningPlan` with IXSCAN and there *should not* be a SORT stage (a sort operation that uses an index will not have the sort stage).

---

**Note About Query Filter Document:**

The query filter: `{ $and: [ { "type":"normal" }, {"timestamp":{ $gte:ISODate("2018-01-10T00:00:00.000Z") } }, { "timestamp": { $lt:ISODate("2018-01-11T00:00:00.000Z") } } ] }`

In the query, you *don't need to use* the `$and` operator. The query filter can be written somewhat in a simpler way as follows:

```
find( { "type":"normal", "timestamp": { $gte:ISODate("2018-01-10T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt:ISODate("2018-01-11T00:00:00.000Z") } } ).sort(...)...
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It was really helpful~!!