# how to configure mongodb index for sorting by value within time range?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection like below

```
tx_collection
    - value
    - from
    - to
    - timestamp
```

What I want to extract from the collection is the highest 100 values within certain time period.

For example,

```
db.getCollection('tx_collection').find({"timestamp":{$gte:ISODate("2018-01-10T00:00:00.000Z")}}).sort({"value":-1}).limit(100)
```

For query performance, I created index like

```
{value: -1, timestmap: 1}
```

But, when I run find query with the index, it took too much time, more than 10secs.

One of test query is like this

```
db.getCollection('tx_collection').find({"timestamp": {$gte: ISODate("2019-10-16T22:09:12.000Z")}}).sort({"value":-1}).limit(100)
```

So, when I tried again with `executionStats`, `nReturned` of inputStage `IXSCAN` is > 100.
What I expected `nReturned` is 100.

## My question is, is my index setting is wrong? And if it's wrong, what is correct index?

([This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584973/how-to-configure-mongodb-index-for-sorting-by-value-within-time-range-with-certa) is what I asked before. And current case is a little bit different from the linke case)

Comment: Please include in the post - the `explain` output (use "executionStats" mode)

Comment: @prasad_
Thank you for your response. Finally I resolved this issue.

Comment: You can post some details of how you have resolved the issue; it will be useful for others who visit this page later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is self resolution.

I finally resolved after reading and understanding fully [this document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/).

The successive query is like this:

```
db.getCollection('tx_collection').find({"value": {$gte: 0}, "timestamp": {$gte: ISODate("2019-10-16T22:09:12.000Z")}}).sort({"value":-1}).limit(100)
```

with index `{value: -1, timestmap: 1}`

Adding additional query prefix, `{"value": {$gte: 0}`, the index can be used.